# How can I sync the literature from a Mendeley group with Sharelatex?

Tags: mendeley, sharelatex

I have a group in Mendeley with a bunch of articles, and I would like to sync it with Sharelatex. However it only seems to sync with the articles in my personal Mendeley and I'm having a hard time making Sharelatex sync with only my desired group.

However, even testing it out with my personal Mendeley, I can't quite seem to get it to generate the Mendeley list in Sharelatex. Is there any special package that I need?

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is as follow:

1. Use Dropbox integration for the project, and find the project folder
   in your Dropbox Apps folder.
2. Use Mendeley to save the whole library in that folder. I think you can only get the file name as library.bib. Your group references will be there. In a moment it gets synced by Dropbox, sharelatex will see it.

This solution works for me but seems a bit dirty.